# In Javascript, readFile method Returns a empty Array, But when console log data are shown in console

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, file-upload

I want to add all images to an array. But when I the following code returns an empty array. However when I console log , the data regarding to the images are shown as [like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLq5S.png). Can anyone give me a solution

This is my code

```
const readImages = uploader => {
      let images = []

      const selectedfiles = uploader.files

      for (let index = 0; index < selectedfiles.length; index++) {
        const fileReader = new FileReader()

        fileReader.onload = fileLoadedEvent => {
          images.push(fileLoadedEvent.target.result)
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(selectedfiles[index])
      }

      return images;
    }//End of readImages

    this._qs('#uploadImages').addEventListener('input', () => {
      const images = readImages(this._qs("#uploadImages"))
      console.log(images)
      for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
        this._qs('#previewImages').innerHTML += `<img src="${images[index]}" alt="image-${index}"/>`
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `images` are pushed to your array `onload`, meaning that it happens asynchronously. You can't act on the images until they've been returned to the browser. Best way to handle this is to have `readImages` return a `Promise.all()`, and have each, individual image load as it's own Promise that you push to the `Promise.all()` array.

```js
const readImage = (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => resolve(result);
    fileReader.onerror = () => reject(fileReader.error);

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });

const readImages = ({ files }) => {
  if (!files) {
    return Promise.reject('No files provided');
  }
  const imgPromises = [];
  files.forEach((file) => imgPromises.push(readImage(file)));

  return Promise.all(imgPromises);
};

// The input 'event' target will contain the value of the field
const onInput = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  readImages(value).then((imgArray) => {
    const preview = document.getElementById('previewImages');
    imgArray.forEach((img, index) => {
      preview.innerHTML += `<img src="${img}" alt="image_${index}" />`;
    });
  });
};

document.getElementById('uploadImages').addEventListener('input', onInput);
```

**Note**: This is really raw code, to give you an idea on the basics, and doesn't check your final result set for errors. It also uses object destructuring, which won't work in older browsers.